# What does Dither do in Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

What does Dither do in Cycles and what's the right value to set?

Answer (score 9):

Dithering is a post-processing step that reduces the banding caused by insufficient bitdepth by adding some controlled noise to the image.

Dithering set to 0:
[image: 0 dither]

Dithering set to 1:
[image: dither = 1]

With Blender's internal renderer, I almost always set it to 1 to avoid banding, but with Cycles, it's less useful because Cycles introduces its own noise anyway.

Comment: Note, its possible to use Cycles in a way which avoids noise, so there may still be some use for dither, see: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?332447-FAST-and-NOISE-FREE-CYCLES-renders-are-here!